# SQL SERVER select like + COUNT

Tags: sql-server

Necesito hacer una solaconsulta como las siguientes:

```
 select COUNT(authorization_number) as number from buyOrder b where authorization_number!='' 
 select * from buyOrder where authorization_number like '% %'
```

Donde el valor del **LIKE** debe ser el número resultante de la primera consulta

Answer (score 1):

Se puede guardar el resultado de la primera consulta en una variable y usarla en la segunda consulta.

```
DECLARE @number VARCHAR(30) = (SELECT Count(authorization_number) AS number 
   FROM   buyorder b 
   WHERE  authorization_number != ''); 

SELECT * 
FROM   buyorder 
WHERE  authorization_number LIKE Concat('%', @number, '%')
```

Answer (score 1):

Una opción es utilizar **cross join** entre ambas consultas. Cada registro de la tabla buyOrder tendrá 1 valor de la lectura de *"Number"*

Utilizando tablas de expresión común

```
 With c as (
    Select Cast ((COUNT(authorization_number)) as varchar(10)) as number 
    from buyOrder b where authorization_number!='' 
    )
    select * 
    from buyOrder cross join c
    where authorization_number like '%'+c.number +'%';
```

O hacerlo como una tabla derivada.

```
select * 
from buyOrder cross join 
(
    Select Cast ((COUNT(authorization_number)) as varchar(10)) as number 
        from buyOrder b where authorization_number!='' 
) as c
where authorization_number like '%'+c.number +'%';
```

[Cross join](https://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/sqlserverya/temarios/descripcion.php?inicio=50&cod=76&punto=70)

[Tablas de expresión común](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2018/12/18/with-cte-tablas-de-expresion-comun-1/)

[Tablas derivadas](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/11/06/tabla-derivada/)